# Inexplicable results after using ind2sub in Matlab

Tags: image, debugging, matlab

I am having some problems in matlab i don't understand. The following piece of code analyses a collection of images, and should return a coherent image (and always did).

But since I've put an if-condition in the second for-loop (for optimisation purposes) it returns an interlaced image.

I don't understand why, and am getting ready to throw my computer out the window. I suspect it has something to do with `ind2sub`, but as far as i can see everything is working just fine! **Does anyone know why it's doing this?**

```
function imageMedoid(imageList, resizeFolder, outputFolder, x, y)

    % local variables
    medoidImage = zeros([1, y*x, 3]);
    alphaImage = zeros([y x]);
    medoidContainer = zeros([y*x, length(imageList), 3]);

    % loop through all images in the resizeFolder
    for i=1:length(imageList)

        % get filename and load image and alpha channel
        fname = imageList(i).name;
        [container, ~, alpha] = imread([resizeFolder fname]);

        % convert alpha channel to zeros and ones, add to alphaImage
        alphaImage = alphaImage + (double(alpha) / 255);

        % add (r,g,b) values to medoidContainer and reshape to single line
        medoidContainer(:, i, :) = reshape(im2double(container), [y*x 3]);

    end

    % loop through every pixel
    for i=1:(y * x)

        % convert i to coordinates for alphaImage
        [xCoord, yCoord] = ind2sub([x y],i);

        if alphaImage(yCoord, xCoord) == 0

            % write default value to medoidImage if alpha is zero
            medoidImage(1, i, 1:3) = 0;

        else

        % calculate distances between all values for current pixel
        distances = pdist(squeeze(medoidContainer(i,:,1:3)));

        % convert found distances to matrix of distances
        distanceMatrix = squareform(distances);

        % find index of image with the medoid value
        [~, j] = min(mean(distanceMatrix,2));

        % write found medoid value to medoidImage
        medoidImage(1, i, 1:3) = medoidContainer(i, j, 1:3);

        end

    end

    % replace values larger than one (in alpha channel) by one
    alphaImage(alphaImage > 1) = 1;

    % reshape image to original proportions
    medoidImage = reshape(medoidImage, y, x, 3);

    % save medoid image
    imwrite(medoidImage, [outputFolder 'medoid_modified.png'], 'Alpha', alphaImage);

end
```

I didn't include the whole code, just this function (for brevity's sake), if anyone needs more (for a better understanding of it), please let me know and i'll include it.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if-loop". If isn't a loop.

Comment: @MattBurland, you're right. Fixed it. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no. I have only a passing familiarity with MatLab. Presumably there is something wrong with your logic in the if condition. I did notice you have alphaImage(yCoord, xCoord). Are you sure those are the right way around?

Comment: That's what i thought. I've checked the indexes, to see if they're in the right order (which is very illogical in matlab, compared to java for example), but as far as i can see they are.

I've even checked the values of all the variables manually in the debugger, but they were all right. Which is why i don't understand why the image comes out with black stripes on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `ind2sub`, you give the size `[x y]`, but the actual size of `alphaImage` is `[y x]` so you are not indexing the correct location with `xCoord` and `yCoord`.

Comment: I don't think that's it. If i change my code according to your suggestion (`ind2sub([y x],i)`), i get an index out of bounds error..

Comment: Did you change the entire line?  Because you also had the two arguments that you were assigning to in reverse as well.  Should be:
`[yCoord, xCoord] = ind2sub([y x],i);`
I haven't tried to execute your entire script, but this line is definitely incorrect, as the size argument to `ind2sub` must match the size of the array or you will be indexing into the wrong element.

Comment: You're right, that was it! Ok, i feel pretty stupid right now. Thanks for helping!